# Cycle in parsing with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to parse the site with library lxml and do the next cycle:

```
for row in html.xpath("//tr/*"):
    result = row.text
    print(result)
```

And get output:

```
8-800-500-1231
John Smith
8-800-600-1245
Tommy Atkins
8-800-800-8314
Joe Blow
```

But how do I get output like this?

```
["8-800-500-1231", "John Smith"], ["8-800-600-1245", "Tommy Atkins"], ["8-800-800-8314", "Joe Blow"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following list comprehension:

```
list_vars = [
    "8-800-500-1231",
    "John Smith",
    "8-800-600-1245",
    "Tommy Atkins",
    "8-800-800-8314",
    "Joe Blow"
]

print [list(var) for var in zip(list_vars[::2], list_vars[1::2])]
```

I think it would be better to keep them as tuples rather than list. If you want to keep them as tuples then you can do this:

```
>>> zip(list_vars[::2], list_vars[1::2])
[('8-800-500-1231', 'John Smith'), ('8-800-600-1245', 'Tommy Atkins'), ('8-800-800-8314', 'Joe Blow')]
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not need to get a list of the "result".

Comment: @JohnSmith Just print the list, and you will have the same thing.

Comment: But this is not a list.

Comment: @JohnSmith It is an iterable. Just replace `list_vars` with the expression `html.xpath("//tr/*")`, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Okay, but where's the most important thing - "result = row.text" After all, for that I did the whole cycle.